# How to derive Jordan curve theorem for three arcs from the two arc version?

Tags: connectedness, plane-curves

The Jordan curve theorem can be stated as follows:

> Let $p,q\in\mathbb R^2$, $p\ne q$ and $a,b$ be arcs between $p$ and $q$ intersecting only in the endpoints. Then $a\cup b$ divides $\mathbb R^2$ into $2$ connected components, each of which has $a\cup b$ as a boundary.

There's an obvious generalization for three arcs which I think should follow from this, but I'm unable to prove that:

> Let $p,q\in\mathbb R^2$, $p\ne q$ and $a,b,c$ be arcs between $p$ and $q$ intersecting only in the endpoints. Then $a\cup b\cup c$ divides $\mathbb R^2$ into $3$ connected components with boundaries $a\cup b$, $b\cup c$, $c\cup b$.

Is it really supposed to be that hard or am I missing something obvious?

What I have so far:
 Let $A=\operatorname{int} (b\cup c)$, $B=\operatorname{int} (c\cup a)$, $C=\operatorname{int} (a\cup b)$ be the bounded components,
 $X=\operatorname{ext} (b\cup c)$, $Y=\operatorname{ext} (c\cup a)$, $Z=\operatorname{ext} (a\cup b)$ the unbounded components and
$a^\circ=a\setminus\{p,q\}$, $b^\circ=b\setminus\{p,q\}$, $c^\circ=c\setminus\{p,q\}$ the intermediate points of the arcs.
By final components I mean the components of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{a\cup b\cup c\}$.

Assuming $c^\circ\subseteq C$, we see that $Z$ is the final unbounded component ($Z$ can only get smaller as we add $c^\circ$ to the separating set $a\cup b$, but it won't, because $Z\cap c^\circ\subseteq Z\cap C=0$).
If $a\subseteq A$, then by the same reasoning $X$ is also the final unbounded component, but that's a contradiction, because $\operatorname{bd} Z=a\cup b\ne b\cup c=\operatorname{bd}X$. Therefore $a\subseteq X$ and $A$ is a final component (we add $a$ outside of $A$). Similarly $B$ is final.

So I have $3$ components with the desired properties, but why can't there be a fourth component? (ie. why $A\cup c^\circ\cup B = C$, I can only prove $\subseteq$)
Additionally I assumed $c^\circ\subset C$, I can do that if I use inversion, but I'd be happier I had a proof without that, so I have an additional question:

> Is there a simple proof why $a^\circ\subseteq X$, $b^\circ\subseteq Y$, $c^\circ\subseteq Z$ can't happen?

I actually can prove the whole thing using the Jordan–Schönflies theorem (straightening one of the circles and some sphere projections), but there must be a simpler way just from the Jordan's curve theorem (at least I hope).

Comment: Are you allowed to use $H_2(D^2,S^1)\not=0$?

Comment: @user72694 Assume no, since I know next to nothing about homology. It's not that I'm not allowed to do something, this is not a homework. I'm just curious about an elementary proof (assuming Jordan curve theorem).

Comment: While I do not see how to use the **statement** of the Jordan curve theorem to do what you want, it should be possible to use its **proof**. The proof in Munkres' "Topology", for example, uses nothing more than Van Kampen's theorem and some connectivity lemmas regarding 2-manifolds. With some work, I'm pretty confident you can write a proof of what you want using the same tools.

Comment: I'll throw in, though, that your life will become easier if you learn about singular homology; that's a more straightforward route to proving the Jordan curve theorem and the application you are asking about. For instance, the "connectivity lemmas" of my previous comment all can be done using the Mayer-Vietoris theorem of homology. And that's still a lot simpler than the Schonflies theorem.

Comment: @LeeMosher Well, maybe I should look into that. If it doesn't follow so easily, then it's pretty surprising to me that this (IMO very useful) fact doesn't have a name (that would also be OK for me, or some reference to this claim). I was actually trying to prove another problem when I realized it would be really nice if knew an arc divides a Jordan curve into 2 parts. I guess I'll post it as another question, but my hope of an elementary solution is now low :)

Comment: For a name, I will recommend the Alexander Duality theorem (closely related to the Poincare Duality theorem). It lets you compute the homology of $S^n-X$ where $X$ is any simplicial complex embedded in $S^n$. For example, if $n=2$ and if $X$ is a connected graph with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges then the number of path components of $S^2-X$ ($=$ rank of $H_0(S^n-X;\mathbb{Z})$) is equal to $1-V+E$ ($=$ rank of $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, also for the motivation to look more into algebraic topology.

Comment: Yup, glad to oblige.